# how to setup drupal site locally and then move to production server....

Tags: php, drupal-7, development-environment, setup-deployment

My client have hosting services that has low bandwidth allocation, so He wants me to setup Drupal website to my local machine and after finalize, move to server.

As I'm not that much familiar with drupal database structure and how to move drupal from one server to another with database... can someone please advice me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running windows 
I Use wamp , i tried several other solution , that was the best clear cut
Refer to this document on [how to install wamp & drupal on windows step by step
][1]

[1]: https://drupal.org/node/1995312 "how to install wamp & drupal on windows step by step
"

By the time you succeed in doing so , you'll have read enough material to help you restore the drupal installation & the database to server.